Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version with matching compatibility

e: This version (1.3.2) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.7.20 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.9.23 which is not known to be compatible.

The error is pretty self explanatory. For other projects matching the compatibility has done just fine. For some reason, no matter what I do in this project, the error persists. There is no reference to a compose compiler that is 1.3.2. Only the main app uses compose. I have tried cleaning/invalidating with the same result.
It is a multi-module project. The gradle build scripts are all using the same kotlin version.
build.gradle (project)
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.9.23'
        compose_version = '1.6.5'
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = '1.5.11'
        ...
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        ...
    }
}

build.gradle (app)
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

    // Compose
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

    // somewhere on a google doc it noted to NOT include this. Here just in case.
    // implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
}

build.gradle (module a)
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
}

build.gradle (module b)
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}


There is also settings.gradle to check.

@SimonJacobs only thing in settings.gradle are module includes but i will update original post with it.

This worked for me, try replace this line
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion

with:
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion rootProject.ext.kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion

When i created empty project with your examples kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion was referencing to ComposeOptions#kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion which is probably having the default value 1.3.2 so it was setting the same value from itself to itself, instead of taking value from ext properties.

Thank you! It was indeed referencing itself.
